# Using SQL IN Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a query like :

```
declare @aID varchar(max)='1'
declare @pID varchar(max)=' '
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE 
(PId = @PID or @pID='') AND (AID = @aID or @aID = '')
```

This query works fine.
**But now, I want to use 'IN' clause.**

```
declare @aID varchar(max)='1,2'
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE 
(PId = @PID or @pID='') AND (AID IN (@aID) or @aID = '')
```

But this last query gives me an error.

```
Error : 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int'
```

I do not want to change the design of my Table1

How can I make this possible ?

Comment: Declaring your parameter AS XML offers you the chance to pass what ever structured data you want into a SP or and UDF... It's quite easy to deal with (simple) XML, SQL-Server does a great job here...

Answer (score 1):

`@vars` are inserted as a single "chunk". it's not the DB's job to decide that it's actually MULTIPLE separate comma-separated values.

If you want `1,2` to be treated as two values, you''ll have to use dynamic sql, e.g.

```
query = "SELECT ... IN (" + @var + ")";
exec query;
```

Comment: I did that, it works only If i specify a value. If no value is passed then I get an error. For example `query = "SELECT ... IN (" + @var + ") or (" + @var + ") = ''''  ";
exec query; ` will give me an error when I pass empty spring

Comment: then put in some conditinoal log to add the `in` clause if you pass in something, otherwise skip it entirely.

Comment: MarcB the OP wants @AID to be eventually be a paramter from a strored proc. I don't think I need to say why this changes things

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use a comma dilimited value for your in you might want to use a table variable

```
declare @ids table ( aid int ) ;
INSERT INTO @ids (aid) Values (1)(2);

declare @idCount  int;
SELECT @idCount = COUNT(aID) FROM @ids;  

SELECT * from Table1 
WHERE 
(PId = @PID or @pID='') 
 AND (
         AID IN (SELECT aid from @ids) 
       or @idCount =0)
```

If you really wanted to keep the comma delimited values you can also use a [split function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703/119477)

```
SELECT * from Table1 
    WHERE 
    (PId = @PID or @pID='') 
     AND (
             AID IN (SELECT item from dbo.SplitString(@aid, ',') ) 
           or @aid = "")
```

Comment: I am having this as a Store Proc. How can I insert values 1,2 ?

Comment: Are you saying that @aID is a parameter?

Comment: For the other part, I get Error as **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

Comment: Yes, @aID is a Parameter.

Comment: You should have said. In that case see [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/337704/119477) I pefer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337864/119477) which uses table-values parmeters

Comment: Also the error you're getting with split is because you wrote `IN (Select * from..)` you need to write `IN (SELECT item ... `

Comment: WHen I use your splitstring query and keep OR between Pid and Aid, I always get all the result despite of keeping values.